# calling two methods which are calling a celery task synchronously in python

Tags: python, celery

I have some methods like below-

```
@app.task
def post():
    ....

def a():
    ...
    post.delay()

def b():
    ...
    post.delay()

def c():
    a()
    b()
```

I want a(),b() to be executed synchronously inside c(). I have multiple celery workers so it is not going to be done by default. I have looked at chains/chords but I think they only work when a() and b() themselves are celery task. Can this be achieved somehow or I need to rewrite my methods?

Comment: Won't the methods `a()` and `b()` be executed synchronously already, since you are not calling `a.delay()` and `b.delay()`?

Comment: a() and b() are not delayed but post() is. My bad. editing the post. So a() and b() are called synchronously but post() that they are calling may not be right?

Comment: So when you call `c()`, it will in turn call `a()` and `b()` which will then each create a celery task? As I understand it, in this case when the code is run, you will have two tasks in the queue, one called by each of the functions. You are saying you need to guarantee that the `post()` called by `a` will be executed before the one called by `b`?

Comment: yes exaclty this^

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this in celery, since the library is meant exactly to do asynchronous tasks. You can probably achieve what you want implementing some kind of lock. You can have `b` pass the task id generated by `a` and then have some code in `post` that checks whether that task has finished. If not, it can have a `while` loop to wait for it to finish. Not very elegant, I think. But could work.

Comment: Do you think chain() will work here? I read about it but not very familiar and hence not sure. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains . So, essentially chaining a and b, not sure if I can even do that.

Comment: It could work. I have no experience with it, though.